# Binary Search for finding Magic Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm practicing binary search and I'm running into a wall when trying to implement it to find the "magic index" in an array. The magic index is `A[i] == i`.

I've found some implementations in [Java using recursion](http://comproguide.blogspot.com/2014/02/finding-magic-index-of-array.html), but I'm trying to avoid doing this recursively because recursion is expensive (and I want to see if binary search is appropriate here).

Here is my code:

```
function magicIndex(arr) {
  var result = arr, mid;
  while (result.length > 1) {
    mid = Math.floor(result.length / 2);

    if (result[mid] === mid) {
      return arr.indexOf(result[mid]);
    } else if (mid > result[mid]) {
      result = result.slice(mid+1, result.length);
    } else {
      result = result.slice(0, mid);
    }
  }
  return arr.indexOf(result.pop());
}
```

The problem is that the algorithm incorrectly slices the array to the wrong side on certain test runs.

For example, `[-10, -3, 0, 2, 4, 8]` returns `4`, but `[-10, 1, 0, 2, 5, 8]` returns `4` as well.

Comment: You did not mention that array is sorted

Comment: @MBo I'm not sure if you are trying to confirm from the OP whether his array is sorted, but if not, binary search assumes a sort, doesn't it?

Comment: @Jose, binary search works only on a sorted array, your second array isn't sorted.

Comment: @0xc0de Probably, there was no unsorted array example in the moment when I was writing my comment (now I am not sure - either question was edited, or I missed it)

Comment: @MBo, strange, even I felt I hadn't seen any examples when I commented first, then I deleted it and wrote another :)

Answer (score 3):

Your second array isn't sorted and [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) works only on a sorted array.

Comment: Thank you, I must've left off the negative sign when sandboxing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're practicing, I think it is good for you to code it by yourself but I'll give you a guide.

Use this algorithm (Note that input array should be sorted already, otherwise implement a sorting method):

```
  int arr[n];
  K ← 1; //search key
  l ← 0; r ← n - 1;
  while l ≤ r do
      m ← floor((l + r)/2)
      if K = arr[m]
          return m
      else if K < arr[m]
          r ← m − 1
      else
          l ← m + 1
  return −1
```

This will output the index of your search key, -1 if key is not found.

Comment: This algorithm will not find a 'magic index', will it? The logic in OPs solution seems correct to me.

Comment: just set the key to the intended index. the algorithm is for generic purposes; `m ← floor((l + r)/2); K ← m;`

Comment: What is 'intended index'? In fact you don't need `K` here, you are fine with just `m == arr[m]`. I'm pointing it out because there is no problem with OP's algo.

Comment: I believe this is his problem: "The problem is that the algorithm incorrectly slices the array to the wrong side on certain test runs."

Comment: But he's wrong in saying that. The code is given by him, so anyone can confirm.

Comment: @John Is No  Because he used unsorted array while method is intended for sorted ones

Comment: Yes, it was a typo in the second array. Sorry about the confusion.